# Angular 7 - Deleting row from a dynamically generated table

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete a row from a dynamically generated table. To begin with, I am  trying to upload multiple files using third party `ngx-file-drop` component. 
I am iterating  through files object which is of the type NgxFileDropEntry. This object has only two properties called fileentry and relative path. While looping through the object however I am able to assign `selectedDocumentItem` and `selectedDate` in html code which is visible during runtime in the component while debugging, but complains at compile time.

I had used the above approach so that I could save records when the user clicks the upload button as all values are available via the object. 
I need to find the unique identifier for the row to delete it. I am unable to now since the object doesn't expose the properties that I am adding to it.

**html**

```
<div class="upload-table">
    <table id="table1" class="center" >

        <tbody class="upload-name-style">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index"  [attr.id]="item.id">

            <td> <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="item.relativePath" style="width: 350px" /></td>
            <td><kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDocumentItem"  [data]="DocumentTypes"  [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                    [filterable]="false" textField="Name"  valueField="Id">
            </kendo-dropdownlist></td>
            <td>  <kendo-datepicker style="width: 200px" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDate"></kendo-datepicker></td>
            <button id="remove" (click)="deleteRow(i)">DELETE </button>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
deleteRow(id) {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i){
            if (this.files[i].id === id) {
                this.files.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
}
```

This is how the json looks like when I click the delete button

```
[{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":6,"Name":"Constitutional Documents"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-09T23:00:00.000Z"},{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":10,"Name":"Manager Letters"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-13T23:00:00.000Z"},{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":7,"Name":"Regulation / References"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-30T23:00:00.000Z"}]
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about deleting from the table by index you passing in the function:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of files; let index=index"  [attr.id]="item.id">
    ...
    <button id="remove" (click)="deleteRow(index)">DELETE </button>
</tr>
```

immutable way:

```
deleteRow(index) {
  this.files = this.files.filter((_filter, key) => key !== index);
}
```

mutable way:

```
deleteRow(index) {
  this.files.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: How about only doing this  this.files.splice(id,1);

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                      
                      
                        <button id="remove" (click)="deleteRow(i)">DELETE </button>
                    </tr>

Comment: See my updated answer. You don't need `for` to do it in mutable way.

Comment: Any advantages of doing it immutable way